# Java - How to configure log4j2.xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websphere, log4j2, tomcat8.5

I want to configure log4j2.xml file via my applicationContext.xml not web.xml. If this log4j2.xml file exist in classpath, I can't make any change in this file. So, I should configure with this applicationContext.xml.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```xml
<bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass"
                  value="org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="getContext" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>false</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="log4jContext" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="log4jInitialization"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="setConfigLocation"/>
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>C:/projects/conf/log4j2.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I think LoggerContext class does not have a setConfigLocation() method because getContext() return log4j-api's LoggerContext class not log4j-core's.

How can I handle this situation? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to externalize log4j configuration ?

Comment: Yes, I want to change log4j2.xml file's location and contents but If I configure log4j2 in web.xml, I can't make any change without deploying new release because web.xml located in classpath. So, I should configure in applicationContext.xml.

Comment: Can you try the following and see if it works for you. a) Add 
 logging.config=${user.home}/projectName/log4j-yourLogging.properties in an application properties file that will be residing in the directory where you start the application , b) This application.properties will override the /resources/application.properties and, the log4j-yourLogging.properties will be used on the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used code as shown below, and I succedded when I using Tomcat Server but If I use WebSphere Server, Program does not print logs into file.

```
<bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass"
              value="org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="getContext" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>false</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="log4jContext" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="log4jInitialization"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setConfigLocation"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <!--<value>classpath:log4j2.xml</value>-->
            <value>file:c:/projects/conf/log4j2.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: The above configuration is kind of reconfiguring the logcontext making it miss few lines written by application. So, instead of getConext and setting location, can we initialise the logcontext for application with our log4j2.xml location?